# Microsoft Excel Security Warning - Pop Up

Tags: html, excel, certificate, ssl-certificate, popupwindow

I am getting this Error when i click a link on an internal company site.

The link is pointing to an excel spreadsheet, but the link does not end in .xls or anything like that.

This works in chrome correctly, but in internet explorer it does not.

The page displays the data in a HTML formatted page, i.e it doesn't look like an excel spreadsheet.

Any thoughts on how to get rid of this error.

I have tried http and https with no luck.

Sorry i cannot post what the page looks like, regardless it is a spreadsheet that is being formatted into a HTML page, for users to view the data.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Why do people vote down, what more can i say?

Comment: Don't let it bother you - I upvoted this.

Answer (score 2):

Check this information about Office 2013 error from Microsoft: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_integration__sharepoint/2015/04/20/office-2013-error-certificate-error-the-application-experienced-an-internal-error-loading-the-ssl-libraries-when-opening-files/

Comment: I'm sad... My organization doesn't seem to have a way around this! : |